# Checking if a tensor is rectangular at compile-time (i.e. all extents of a multidimensional array are equal)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gpgpu, template-meta-programming

I am writing a templated GPGPU tensor sum function (mainly for fun, but also to further my understanding of template metaprogramming and GPGPU programming), and I want to do some static assertions to prevent invalid use of the function.

One of the requirements of the C++ AMP `array_view` class is that it be rectangular (i.e. all the extents are the same).

However, I'm not entirely sure how to do this. Currently my function looks something like:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
auto TensorSum( T t, U u )->decltype( std::remove_all_extents<T>::type + std::remove_all_extents<U>::type )
{
    using SumType = decltype(std::remove_all_extents<T>::type + std::remove_all_extents<U>::type);

    static_assert( std::rank<T>::value == std::rank<U>::value, "The two tensors must have the same rank" );

    // ToDo: Put a static assertion here to ensure tensors are rectangular

    SumType arrSum[std::rank<T>::value * std::extent<U>::value];

    concurrency::array_view<std::remove_all_extents<T>::type, std::rank<T>::value> a( std::extent<T>::value, t );
}
```

My main problem is that the rank is a variable and there is no way to perform iteration at compile-time.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this is to make the values of the class templates as well (i used a different example)

```
template <typename T, typename U, T t, U u>
void blah()
{
  static_assert(t==u,"sizes must be equal");
  printf("foo");
}
int main()
{
  blah<int,int,10,10>();
  //blah<int,int,10,15>();error C2338 (Visual Studio): "sizes must be equal"
}
```

I recently made a matrix class this way:

```
template <size_t M,size_t N>
class Matrix
{
    double values_[M][N];
    ...

};
```

and than the operators worked like this instead:

```
 template <size_t M, size_t N>
 operator +(const Matrix<M,N>& lhs,const Matrix<M,N>& rhs){...}
```

Because the size was part of the type, it made it easy to make the operator only available for valid cases like that. However, an alternate would be:

```
 template <size_t ML, size_t NL,size_t MR,size_t NR>
 operator +(const Matrix<ML,NL>& lhs,const Matrix<MR,NR>& rhs)
 {
    static_assert(ML==MR && NL==NR,"Matrix dimensions must aggree");
     ...
 }
```

Both methods are OK, but if you don't associate the sizes with some sort of template argument you can only do runtime checks (AKA exception handling).

Answer (score 0):

The following `boost::mpl` code will do what you ask.
The key is reformulate your loop into an accumulation and call `boost::mpl::fold`.

```
    #include <boost/mpl/range_c.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/fold.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/int.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/bool.hpp>
    #include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
    template <class T>
    struct is_rectangular
    {
        struct rectangular_check
        {
            template <class Value, class Dim>
            struct apply
            {
                typedef typename and_<
                    Value,
                    bool_<std::extent<T>::value == std::extent<T, Dim::value>::value>
                    >::type type;
            };
        };

        typedef typename fold<
            range_c<
                unsigned,
                0,
                std::rank<T>::value
                >,
            true_,
            rectangular_check
            >::type type;
    };
```

So now your function (which I've modified to accept raw array types) looks like:

```
    template <typename T, typename U>
    auto TensorSum(const T & t, const U &u )->
        decltype(std::declval<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type>() +
                 std::declval<typename std::remove_all_extents<U>::type>())
    {
        using SumType = decltype(std::declval<typename std::remove_all_extents<T>::type>() +
                                 std::declval<typename std::remove_all_extents<U>::type>());
        static_assert(std::rank<T>::value == std::rank<U>::value,
                      "The two tensors must have the same rank");

        // ToDo: Put a static assertion here to ensure tensors are rectangular
        std::cout << std::rank<T>::value << ' ' << std::extent<T>::value << std::endl;
        static_assert(is_rectangular<T>::type::value, "First tensor is not rectangular");
        static_assert(is_rectangular<U>::type::value, "Second tensor is not rectangular");

        SumType arrSum[std::rank<T>::value * std::extent<U>::value];
    }

    int main()
    {
        int a[10][10];
        TensorSum(a, a);
        return 0;
    }
```

This will fail to compile if you change the dimensions of `a` in `main` to be different, as desired.

This can of course be written without boost's help, but I prefer using it where I can.